# Is there a way to write a sql statement, where only the columns with a specific datatype are shown?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mariadb

Is there a way to write a sql statement, where only the columns with a specific datatype are shown?

Important:

- the table can have all kind of datatypes
- table can have more than one column with the needed datatype
- there are too many table to hardcode the statement
- I use mariaDB and postgres

For example:

```
calA is bigint
colB is varchar

+------+------+
| colA | colB |
+------+------+
|   1  |   a  |
|   1  |   a  |
+------+------+
```

Now I want the following result (only bigint):

```
+------+
| colA |
+------+
|   1  |
|   1  |
+------+
```

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL, looking up the types in the information schema metadata tables.

Comment: postgrseql or  mariadb ??

Comment: @scaisEdge I need to do this in both.

Comment: @GordonLinoff any hint on how to do that?

Comment: Its better to tag only one database at a time. you can ask 2 separate questions with different databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `MariaDB`, it is quite easy but in `PostgreSQL` it is tricky:
**For MariaDB**
you can simply write a procedure like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(100),IN col_data_type VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
select group_concat(column_name) into @x from information_schema.columns where table_name=tab_name and data_type=col_data_type;
SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT ", @x, " FROM ",tab_name);
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END
```

and call it like below:

```
call test1('test','varchar');
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=48c861bd298301337704c6c77bfa5c17)

**For Postgresql :**

You can use any of below mentioned approach:

**Approach 1. By creating dynamic query using function:** If you want to run it in your application then you can use this approach

a. Create a function which will return desired query based on table name and datatype like below:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_query(schemaname VARCHAR,tabname VARCHAR, coltype VARCHAR) RETURNS TEXT
AS
$$
DECLARE 
col_list text;
result text;
BEGIN
select  
array_to_string(array_agg(quote_ident(column_name)),',')
from
information_schema.columns 
where table_name=quote_ident(tabname) 
and table_schema=quote_ident(schemaname) 
and data_type=coltype into col_list;

return ('select '|| col_list ||' from ' || quote_ident(schemaname) ||'.'||quote_ident(tabname));

END;
$$
language plpgsql
```

b. Then call above function, which will return the desired query as text which can be use programmatically to get the result:

```
select * from  get_query('public','test','integer');

-- Result : select * from  get_query('public','test','integer');
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f84ea6cd5767ea30f4d2e40bc577939f)

**Approach 2. By creating TYPE and JSONB result dynamically using function:** If you want to run it DB Side only then this workaround will do the things for you:

a. Create a TYPE dynamically according to the result set of table like below:

```
create or replace function create_type(schemaname varchar,tabname varchar, coltype varchar) 
returns void as
$$
declare 
col_list varchar;
begin
select  
array_to_string(array_agg(quote_ident(column_name)||' '|| data_type),',')
from
information_schema.columns where table_name=quote_ident(tabname) and table_schema=quote_ident(schemaname) and data_type=coltype into col_list;

execute format('drop type if exists get_type;');
execute format('create type get_type as ('|| col_list ||')');
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

b. Now create a function which will return the desired result in `JSONB` format:

```
create or replace function get_col(schemaname varchar,tabname varchar, coltype varchar) returns jsonb
as
$$
declare 
col_list text;
x jsonb;
begin
select  
array_to_string(array_agg(quote_ident(column_name)),',')
from
information_schema.columns where table_name=quote_ident(tabname) and table_schema=quote_ident(schemaname) and data_type=coltype into col_list;
execute format('select jsonb_agg(row_to_json(t1)) from (select '|| col_list ||' from test)t1') into x;
return x;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

3. Call both of the function and use `jsonb_populate_recordset` to convert the result in a  table form:

```
select create_type('public','test','character varying');
select * from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::get_col1, 
(select * from get_col('public','test','character varying')));
```

4. If you can afford the result in JSON for programmatic use then you can simply call the function created in second step which will return a JSON Array of desired records. you can call it like below:

```
select * from get_col('public','test','character varying');
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d0f1d4d3f520a37e58d1b149c7a9d9d2)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to dynamically assemble a SQL query.

For example, if you have a PostgreSQL table like:

```
create table t (
  a bigint,
  b varchar(10),
  c bigint
);
```

You can find all columns for a specific type using:

```
select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public'
  and table_name = 't'
  and data_type = 'bigint';
```

Result:

```
table_name  column_name 
----------- ----------- 
t           a           
t           c
```

You can use the result of this query to dynamically assemble the SQL query you want, using your preferred language to do it.

A similar strategy can be used for MariaDB.